# Can i compare the content of 2 different Blob Objects

Tags: java, blob, inputstream

I have 2 BLOB Objects and I want to compare the content within those BLOB objects??

How can i do this in JAVA.

```
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(cis.readAllBytes());
final Blob blob2 = test.reEncrypt(blob, "");
```

I want to compare the content in blob and blob2. My target is to check if the reEncryption gave me the same data or different.

Any leads would be really great. Thanks

```
  final InputStream cis = test.getEncryptingInputStream(is);
  final InputStream resStream = test
                .reEncrypt(cis, "");
  String encodeStr1 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cis.readAllBytes());
  String encodeStr2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(resStream.readAllBytes());
```

encodestr1 and encodestr2 is coming empty. Can you explain how can we compare the content of InputStream as well. Correct me If I am doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like

```
    String string1 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length()));
    String string2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(blob2.getBytes(1, (int)blob2.length()));
    System.out.println(string1.equals(string2));
```

Comment: Another solution is to compare byte by byte while reading both streams. That avoid materializing the whole BLOB in memory (twice). This solution works well, nevertheless, for most cases when the blobs are on the small side.

Comment: @Wladimir If i need to do the similar thing for InputStreams and i want to compare both inputStreams, How can we do this??

Comment: final InputStream cis = test.getEncryptingInputStream(is);
        final InputStream resStream = test
            .reEncrypt(cis, "");
        String encodeStr1 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cis.readAllBytes());
        String encodeStr2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(resStream.readAllBytes());   I am trying this way but this is giving me empty string.